# Fine-uploader with standard form

Tags: fine-uploader, mura

Is there somewhere or does someone know how to use fine-uploader with a basic form, no ajax? I've attempted to use the standard method with Mura CMS and 12 hours later Mura's internal permissions have beaten me.

Comment: Do you want not want to send upload requests with AJAX? Or are you trying to integrate Fine Uploader with an existing form? Or something entirely different?

Comment: I want to use ajax, but Mura CMS 6.1 is not letting me, I have asked the developers about this and there is no straightforward solution. No I dont yet have a form, but can make one if fineuploader can take one...if not I guess I'll just not use something else.

Comment: How are AJAX requests limited? Fine Uploader sends HTTP POST requests (and a few other types, but POSTS are used for the uploads).

Comment: After adding the cfc im using to the exceptions list I still get a random cf (coldfusion) error, even if i return something simple from the method. I traced this all over the place, no matter what I put in my end point the error line num is the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is from the perspective of a Fine Uploader developer, not a user or developer of Mura CMS (which I have no experience with):

Fine Uploader does not have a way -- currently -- to turn AJAX requests off and use a form submit manually. All of this is done internally as Fine Uploader progressively enhances itself as browser features are supported.

If your framework does not allow AJAX requests to be made to it one workaround would be to setup a separate server on another domain just to handle uploads. You would have to enable CORs and setup access-control rules, but this would then allow you to make AJAX requests to upload.

The real question is why does your CMS not allow AJAX and **how** because that might give clues as to another workaround.